# UML context diagram

Tags: uml

May i know what is UML context diagram? I went online and searched for it and what i get is   a system context diagram with process, entity and data storage. If they are the same, why is it called UML context diagram instead of context diagram.

Comment: A system context can be modelled with e.g. a component diagram. The name "context diagram" is not used for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A UML context diagram does not exist. The UML defines many diagram types but no context diagrams. In UML you would use e.g. use case diagrams for the same purpose.

Comment: Owh, i see. Thank you so much. I'm new to documentation and diagram. If i may, can i ask whether context diagram and conceptual diagram are the same diagram?

Comment: Context diagrams are used in a technique called "structured analysis". Conceptual diagram is just a general term for diagrams show only concepts, imo.